# sftp user connection error Debian 11

Tags: debian, sftp

I setup an sftp server following this guide and created a user sftpuser;
https://citizix.com/how-to-set-up-an-sftp-server-on-debian-11-server/

It did work originally when connecting via ftp program but now when I try, I can only connect using my user login account for the machine and can't connect using sftpuser anymore;

Authentication log (see session log for details):
Using username "sftpuser".

Authentication failed.

I know the password is correct but I must have changed folder permissions somehow.
Linux newbie. Please help correct. Thank you

Comment: `changed folder permissions` shouldn't result with `Authentication failed` - not in general but since you changed something, the obvious solution is to change it back

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, I'm not sure what all I did to the box since it stopped working :( So looking for some guidance on setting the config file(s) back to original or something.